# Scrolling after 'intro' class section not working in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js and the scroll does not work after the 'intro' class section. I am able to move upwards in the webpage but while moving downwards it stops after the 'intro' class section. I even tried using normalScrollElements but it still does not work. The code is as below:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Hello
        <div class="intro">
            /* Dummy Text */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

Link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/yash9051/pen/rNpXNYJ

Comment: It works for me using trackpad and using keyboard. I'm on Chrome on Mac. What are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome on Windows

Comment: I can't see any problem on Windows either on the codepen you posted. Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Well, I tried on another PC, it works fine. But is not working on my laptop properly. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: That's weird... so I assume the issue is with the option `scrollOverflow`? Do you still have the issue when you remove this option or use `scrollOverflow: false`?

Comment: When I added scrollOverflow: false, the section with content overlapped the other sections.

Comment: Yeah, but does it scroll?

Comment: It does scroll but does the script face scrolling errors in smaller screen desktops?

Comment: What errors? You haven't mentioned them in your question. Can you update it accordingly or close this one and open a new one with the steps to reproduce your issue?